# How to ensure that tenants can never access other tenants' data in multi-tenant with shared db

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js, multi-tenant

I'm implementing the multi-tenant with a shared database. But I met the problem when I want to query a table that belongs to a specific tenant.

For example:
I have a table `catalog` that has relation to the `tenant` table, at application logic, I always do a query to check a `catalog` belongs to a specific `tenant` or not before having another query to handle `catalog` logic.

So is there any way to make sure the `catalog` belongs to the specific `tenant` without step checking because sometimes I forgot to add this validate step  => doing on `catalog` does not belong to a specific `tenant`?

I use postgres as database, and sequelize as orm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is "Row Level Security". In PostgreSQL it is implemented as [Row Security Policies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html). It allows you to control access to specific rows for specific users.

If your tenants connect to the database using their DB users you can apply a policy:

```sql
CREATE POLICY tenants_catalog ON catalog 
    USING (tenant = current_user);
```

Comment: thank you @Julius Tuskenis, that is what I need